# Split data to plot histograms side-by-side in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am learning R with the Australian athletes data set.

By using ggplot, I can plot a histogram like this.

```
library(DAAG)

ggplot(ais, aes(wt, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5)
```

[image]

By using summary(ais$wt), the 3rd Quartile is 84.12. Now I want to split the data by the wt 84.12. and plot 2 similar histograms accordingly (side by side)

The split is:

```
ais1 = ais$wt[which(ais$wt>=0 & ais$wt<=84.12)]
ais2 = ais$wt[which(ais$wt>84.12)]
```

But I don’t know how to fit them in the plotting. I tried but it doesn't work:

```
ggplot(ais1, aes(wt, fill = sex)) +...
```

How can I plot the histograms (2 similar histograms accordingly, side by side)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the split as a column to your data

```
ais$wt_3q = ifelse(ais$wt < 84.12, "Quartiles 1-3", "Quartile 4")
```

Then use facets:

```
ggplot(ais, aes(wt, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5) +
  facet_wrap(~ wt_3q)
```

[image]

The created variable is a factor, if you specify the order of the levels you can order the facets differently (lots of questions on here showing that if you search for them - same as reordering bars for a ggplot barplot). You can also let the scales vary - look at `?facet_wrap` for more details.

Generally, you *shouldn't* create more data frames. Creating `ais1` and `ais2` is usually avoidable, and your life will be simpler if you use a single data frame for a single data set. Adding a new column for grouping makes it easy to keep things organized.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `ggarrange` to arrange the plot objects for each subset

```
library(DAAG)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
p2 <- ais %>%
         filter(wt>=0,  wt<=84.12) %>%
         ggplot(., aes(wt, fill = sex)) + 
            geom_histogram(binwidth = 5) +
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 30))  


p1 <- ais %>%
         filter(wt>84.12) %>%
         ggplot(., aes(wt, fill = sex)) + 
            geom_histogram(binwidth = 5) +
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 30))  



ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol =2, nrow = 1, labels = c("p1", "p2"))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: thank you again for your kind help. unfortunately I can choose only 1 for the answer. would you mind I pick Gregor's this time, as it has upvotes?

Comment: @MarkK  No problem.  It seems to less verbose (code) than mine.  I would also pick his answer.